# Dropdown list in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

I'm developing an application using `Grails 3.3.10`, I'm trying to make a dropdown list but I'm getting it empty I'm putting the values in `application.yml` file, below is my code.

application.yml:

```
profile:
   accType: ['supplier', 'buyer', 'both']
```

Domain:

```
class Profile {
String accType
static constraints = {
accType(nullable: true, InList: Holders.config.getProperty('profile.accType'))
  }

}
```

_form.gsp

```
<g:select required="" style="width:auto;" class="form-control input" name="accType" from="${Profile.constrainedProperties.accType.inList}" value="${profileInstance?.accType}" valueMessagePrefix="profile.accType"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
static constraints = {
    accType(nullable: true, InList: Holders.config.getProperty('profile.accType'))
}
```

You probably want this:

```
static constraints = {
    accType(nullable: true, inList: Holders.config.getProperty('profile.accType', List))
}
```

Note that `InList` should be `inList` with a lower case `"i"` at the beginning and you want to pass 2 arguments to the `getProperty`, the second argument being the `List` class literal.

Comment: I did as you mentioned but still getting it empty, any other recommendation

Comment: It does work for me.  I put the code in the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/sshebabdropdown.  The dropdown is at https://github.com/jeffbrown/sshebabdropdown/blob/174457c9de60d1972e4dbd3b961630ff02a74fad/grails-app/views/profile/create.gsp#L30 (note that I just dropped the dropped the dropdown in the form to verify that it populates, you probably want to adjust) and the constraints are specified at https://github.com/jeffbrown/sshebabdropdown/blob/174457c9de60d1972e4dbd3b961630ff02a74fad/grails-app/domain/sshebabdropdown/Profile.groovy#L8.  All appears to work.

Comment: If you can share a project which demonstrates the problem, it would be trivial to troubleshoot.  The sample app I linked there took 2 or 3 minutes to create.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, here is a snapshot of the project on Github, still the dropdown empty!!!  https://github.com/sshehab/test

Comment: The problem is at https://github.com/sshehab/test/blob/5a46fe1efe62255cf02c020dabcbdbeda6c61a6f/grails-app/domain/test/Profile.groovy#L8.  If you change `InList` to `inList` then your dropdown list will work because the `inList` constraint will be properly initialized.

Comment: what a silly mistake, really appreciate your support, I didn't  totally realize this as I'm migrating this project from `Grails 2.5.6` so I thought it is the same constraint

Comment: In 2.5.6 the constraint was also called `inList`.  See https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.6/ref/Constraints/inList.html.  I am glad you got it working.